# Selenium (with soda) getEval returning [object Object]

Tags: javascript, testing, selenium, selenium-rc, soda

I'm using soda (https://github.com/LearnBoost/soda) to help me write a couple of selenium tests. However, I'm running into a problem with getEval.

I have these helpers defined:

```
soda.prototype.two = function() {
  return this.getEval('this.browserbot.getCurrentWindow().document.getElementsByTagName("body").length == 1;');                               
}

soda.prototype.one = function() {
  var x = this.two();
  return this.assertValue(x, true);
}
```

In the test, I have:

```
browser                                                                                                                                       
  .chain                                                                                                                                      
  .session()                                                                                                                                  
  .open('/g/48hLQZPRj')
  .one()    
  ...
```

However, this is the test result logs:

```
open: /g/48hLQZPRj
getEval: this.browserbot.getCurrentWindow().document.getElementsByTagName("body").length == 1;
assertValue: [object Object], S
testComplete: 
[Error: assertValue([object Object], S): Element  not found]
```

Why is getEval returning an object?  Why is it not returning a boolean like I expect it to?  What am I missing?  Thanks!

Comment: getElementsByTagName("body")


Selenium is unable to find the body tag, as far as i could understand.

Comment: any idea why? i even put an alert as the first statement in getEval before "this.browserbot.getCurrentWindow()..." and it alerts the value true. even getEval('"a" === "a"') which should return true, actually returns [object Object]...